# Visual Studio Code Javascript Intellisense not working on event object properties

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, events, intellisense

I noticed when trying to call the .target property on the event parameter i'm passing thru, the intellisense doesn't recognize and give me options of the available properties or methods.

Is this normal functionality or is there a way to work around this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rN04.png

Comment: What auto completion would you expect there? You just define a function with some arbitrary parameter named `event`. How is the IDE supposed to have any idea if you are going to call that method via `sharePhoto(123)` or `sharePhoto("123")` or `sharePhoto(someObject)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to make it work by using JSDoc type annotations:

```
/**
 * @param event {YourTypeHere}
 */
let sharePhoto = function (event) {
    // TODO: Write code
}
```

For example, if you type `Event` in between the brackets:

[image: A Visual Studio Code screenshot showing that IntelliSense works after giving 'event' an 'Event' type annotation]

Comment: Note that the {type} should come before the argument name according to the docs: https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#names-types-and-descriptions

Comment: Hi @JPC, thank you for letting me know about this. I never realized that! I guess vscode's default JSDoc template is wrong. My answer does work, but when I put the type first like you're supposed to, vscode also correctly highlights the type.

Comment: That's odd. If I have a `function foo(bar)` and type `/**`, then `Enter`, it'll put them the right way round: `@param {*} bar`. How are you invoking it? Do you maybe have an extension that's not updated or causing issues?

Comment: When I type `/**` and hit enter, it creates a JSDoc template and puts the cursor next to the first parameter name: `@param interestingName |` (where `|` represents the cursor). Tabbing takes me to the following parameters and, finally, the "main" function documentation. I don't think I have any conflicting extensions.

Comment: Okay, it may be if you don't have a jsconfig.json project file. I just tried in an unrelated environment and the type didn't pop up there. Try adding a jsconfig to your project and see if that changes anything: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: @JPC: Now it works! That's good to remember for next time. :)